# How do you write pseudocode for union, intersection and product of a venn diagram of two circles?

Tags: math, set, pseudocode, discrete-mathematics

[image: Venn Diagram]

Assume we have a Venn diagram of two circles. We have to find the union, intersection and the product of them. For example we have sets:

```
A=[a,b,f,g]
B=[b,e,f,h]
```

Union

```
AUB=[a,b,e,f,g,h]
```

Intersection

```
A∩B = [f,g]
```

Product

```
A*B=[ab, ae, af, ah, bb, be, bf, bh, fb, fe, ff, fh, gb, ge, gf, gh]
```

My question is, how do we write these operations in Pseudocode? I don't know how to do it.

Comment: Can you be a bit clearer about what you want ?  For me the expression `A∩B` is perfectly good pseudocode for the intersection of `A` and `B`.

Comment: I was given the task write pseudo code to implement sum, product and difference given the implicit functions A and B (in the form described above). So if I understand correctly, the mathematical operations above can be considered pseudo code. Very much appreciated for your help.

Answer (score 0):

A union B:

```
C := empty set
for each a in A:
    C.add(a)
for each b in B:
    if not C.contains(b) then C.add(b)
```

This has quadratic runtime if implemented using lists/arrays. It has linear runtime if using a hash table/dictionary.

A intersect B:

```
C := empty set
for each a in A:
    if B.contains(a) then C.add(a)
```

Same performance as union.

A x B:

```
C := empty set
for each a in A:
    for each b in B:
        C.add((a,b))
```

This has quadratic runtime but that is unavoidable since the returned result contains on the order of n^2 elements.